# Increment only letter while dragging formula down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have
`='AD Sub Outcomes'!F79` in the formula bar.
While dragging down, I want to increment only the letter, like
`='AD Sub Outcomes'!G79`
`='AD Sub Outcomes'!H79` and so on.

How can I achieve that? I tried to put dollar sign after the letter, but it's not working (`='AD Sub Outcomes'!F$79`).

Comment: Increase how? Do you need to fill down formulas? Or fill right? Or within the same cell?...

Comment: sorry if my question not clear, I want to increase the alphabet only on the same column for the next rows, for example AD Sub Outcomes'!G79, AD Sub Outcomes'!H79, AD Sub Outcomes'!I79. I did manually right now, which is exhausting. the value of AD Sub Outcomes'!G79 is extracting from other sheet. I hope it is clear enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic formula:

```
=INDEX($row_number:$row_number,ROW(start_col_number:start_col_number))
```

In your case:

```
=INDEX('AD Sub Outcomes'!$79:$79,ROW(6:6))
```